# Parameter decorator with an arguement

Tags: typescript

I am trying to inject a generic service and pass it a string after it gets injected.

```
 constructor(@service('item') private itemRep: BaseRepository<Item>) {
    console.log(itemRep.name);
  }
```

This is the decorator:

```
export function service(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, parameterIndex: number, name:string) {
 target['name'] = name;
}
```

But this gives a compile error saying that the arguments supplied do not match.

What should be the correct way of doing it?